# initialize one dimentional array from database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to initialize one dimensional array from database, but it is not initializing.

```
Dim cmdstring As String = "SELECT DISTINCT(category) from inventory"
command = New MySqlCommand(cmdstring, connection)

Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

While reader.Read()
    Dim xValues() As String = reader("category")
End While

connection.Close()
```

Comment: [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Comment: I've corrected the formatting of your post and a couple of typos. Please also include the exact error message you're getting in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dim xValues() As String = reader("category")

This is not the process to initialize an Array. I can assume that you took xValues() as a Dynamic Array. So to initialize with data you can do the followings

```html
        Dim xValues() As String

        While reader.Read()

            ReDim Preserve xValues(xValues.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
            xValues(xValues.GetUpperBound(0)) = reader("category")

        End While
```

You can do it in another way. If you declare it as a list and want to store the data into that list. You can do this as follows

```html
        Dim xValues As New List(Of String)
        While reader.Read()

            xValues.Add(reader("category"))

        End While
```

Hope it can give you a way.